# Google Analytics Example Not Working?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics-api

I have followed the example script here: [Hello Analytics Reporting API V4; JavaScript quickstart for web applications](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/quickstart/web-js)

And have uploaded it on my site.

But the output is lines of codes..
[image]

May I know where could I have gone wrong?

I have replaced the Client ID and View ID inside the source file.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: And what is wrong here? Examine the code and you'll see, that it prints `json` output to the `textarea`, what you actually see.

Comment: As Gino stated correctly the "lines of code" are the `JSON` response from the API. It appears you have had 0 sessions for the last seven days for the particular view ID. Try replacing the view ID with one that has data.